# How to make the default position of horizontal JScrollBar on the right?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I have a program I am working on, the horizontal scrollbar should be in the right-hand position by default, I tried to use `Viewport()` but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
jScrollPane4.getViewport().setViewPosition(new Point(10, 10));
BoxLayout boxlayout = new BoxLayout(categoryPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
BoxLayout boxlayout2 = new BoxLayout(servicePanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
categoryPanel.setLayout(boxlayout);
category cg = new category();
subString ss = new subString();
try {
    List<JButton> buttonList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Category> map = cg.readDatafromJson();
    for (Category item : map) {
        String CAr = ss.SubString(item.getName_ar());
        String SAr = ss.SubString(item.getName_en());
        JButton button = new JButton("<html><p style=\"text-align:right;\"><b>" + CAr + "</b> \n" + SAr + "</P></html>", icon);
        Border line = new LineBorder(Color.BLACK);
        button.setActionCommand(item.getKey());
        button.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        button.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        buttonList.add(button);
        categoryPanel.add(button);
        categoryPanel.revalidate();
        categoryPanel.repaint();
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(PassOrdreCashier.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Scrollbar

[image]

Comment: *"Any ideas?"* [Edit] to add a [mre].

Comment: [`JComponent#scrollRectToVisible`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#scrollRectToVisible(java.awt.Rectangle)) - but I would do some research, as you'd be surprised by how it should be used

Comment: BTW: 1) **Do** act on advice offered by people in comments. 2) **Don't** ask a lesser form of the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71283042/418556) again.

Comment: 1) It is more efficient to do the revalidate() and repaint() once outside the loop. 2) you will also need to wrap the scrollRectToVisible() method in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater().

Comment: can you give me an example , i need more details

Comment: You have NOT posted any code showing how you attempted to use the suggested methods. 1) Read the API for information about each of the methods suggested 2) Search the forum for example that use these methods. This is basic problem solving. If you still have problems then you have been asked to post an [mre].